# How to have text appearance order in numbered bibliography and include authors and years in the text?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing my masters thesis with LaTeX. The thing that I want to have is the possibility to have a bibliography such as the one reported here, that is, a bibliographical order by citation appearance (N.B. in text, not in the .bib file!) and at the same time have the possibility to include authors in the text, with commands such as \citeauthors{...} and so on.

I know that the second part is possible with natbib, but it doesn't somehow let me have the references in order of appearance in the text.

I read somewhere that the bibliography style 'ieeetr' handles the order of appearance in the text automatically, but this is not compatible with the inserting of authors and years in the text. That is to say, with the 'ieeetr' style it gives me

```
(author?)(year?)
```

as a result for the commands

```
\citeauthor{...} \citeyear{...}
```

because I guess it's not an author-year compatible style.

I also tried makebst but the result doesn't change.

To make it clear, having the code below:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{book} \citeyear{book} \cite{book}
\citeauthor{article} \citeyear{article} \cite{article}
\citeauthor{conference} \citeyear{conference} \cite{conference}

\bibliographystyle{ex}
\bibliography{ex}

\end{document}
```

and this .bib file:

```
@Book{book,
  Title                    = {Book title},
  Author                   = {Book Author},
  Publisher                = {Publisher},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Edition                  = {2},
  Month                    = {June}
}

@Article{article,
  Title                    = {Article title},
  Author                   = {Article Author One and Article Author Two},
  Journal                  = {Journal title of the article},
  Year                     = {1975},
  Pages                    = {230-235},
  Volume                   = {14}
}

@Conference{conference,
  Title                    = {Conference paper title},
  Author                   = {Conference Author One and Conference Author Two and Conference Author Three},
  Booktitle                = {Conference proceedings},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Month                    = {May}
}
```

it gives me these results:

in the text:

[image]

and in the bibliography section:

[image]

which is not what I want.

Instead my desired result would be:

in the text:

[image]

and in the bibliography section:

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the help of `biblatex` package and setting `Biber` as default bibliography.

The option `sorting=none` orders the references by text appearance.

Actually this code works:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ex.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{conference} \citeyear{conference} \cite{conference}
\citeauthor{book} \citeyear{book} \cite{book}
\citeauthor{article} \citeyear{article} \cite{article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And since I'm using `TeXstudio` I had to run LaTeX first, then Biber (using F11 or Tools->Bibliography) and then LaTeX again. Hope this helps someone!